# Trying to echo all lines of texts in a .txt

Tags: php, html

Here is my php code

```
<?php
$myFile = "hidata.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fgets($fh);
fclose($fh);
echo ('<li>' . $theData . '</li>');
?>
```

and here is what in my hidata.txt

```
data1
data2
data3
```

I wanted my code to echo all texts by line like this

```
<li>data1</li>
<li>data2</li>
<li>data3</li>
```

But it echos only `<li>data1</li>`

How can I echo all lines and everytime I add a new new line in the `.txt` file, it will automatically appear in the page.

Comment: You don't have a loop obviously it will only print the first line you have to loop through the lines fgets() read one line at a time

Comment: try this `'<ul><li>'.str_replace(array("\r","\n\n","\n"),array('',"\n","</li>\n<li>"),trim($theData,"\n\r")).'</li></ul>';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) fetches single line from file, you can loop through file to process whole file

Try

```
<?php
$myFile = "hidata.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
while(false !== ($theData = fgets($fh))) {
    echo ('<li>' . $theData . '</li>');
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: it is not showing anything

Comment: @Sadie ah yes I missed parenthesis, I fixed this

Comment: how does this differ from accepted dupe answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can explode it into array and after echo into a foreach

```
$theData = "data1
data2
data3";

$array = explode(PHP_EOL,$theData);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo ('<li>' . $value . '</li>');
}
```

Comment: where is the get from the .txt file bit?

Comment: @treyBake: i think `$theData = "data1
data2
data3";` this part is the assumption of txt file

Comment: $theData is your variable that you use in your example

Comment: @devpro but the point is to get the data from the file, which OP isn't doing successfully

Comment: OP is getting the same data from file as mentioned in this example. but i agreed with you. @treyBake

Comment: @devpro ah I see, misinterpreted your comment haha

Comment: @treyBake: :) and what about down vote :p :p

Comment: @treyBake: another solution: `'<ul><li>'.str_replace(array("\r","\n\n","\n"),array('',"\n","</li>\n<li>"),trim($theData,"\n\r")).'</li></ul>';`